# distinguishing from database for mini market php

Tags: php, database

so I have two animals a black bear and a polar bear. They are linked to my database. what i am trying to achieve: when I use $_Post my black bear will sell for 100.00, but what i want is if the user sells the black bear it will credit 100.00 into the amount and if the user sells the polar bear it will credit 50.00 into the amount. Unfortunately when I click polar bear and sell it it gives me the same amount as the black bear. I want it to give me 50.00. both bears have a row in my databased called type. Here is my code so far:

```
                $resu = mysqli_query(
            $con,
            "SELECT * FROM `animal`"); 



             if(mysqli_num_rows($resu ) > 0){
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resu)){


             $type = $row['type']; 




            if(isset($_POST['go']))
            {
            if($type=="black bear"){

                 $current = $amount+100;

               $query = "UPDATE  users  SET amount=$current WHERE email ='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
                 mysqli_query($query);
            }
            

        if($type=="polar bear"){

             $current = $amount+50;

           $query = "UPDATE  users  SET amount=$current WHERE email ='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
             mysqli_query($query);
        }
```

Comment: You're not initializing `$amount` anywhere. You can just do `UPDATE users SET amount = amount + 50 WHERE ...` right in the SQL. Note also that you are vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: yeah but i want to to update different amounts depending on type

Comment: yeah so for example if the $type was a polar then amount to get back would be 50 then 100 if the $type was a black bear